# How do I install node.js 0.5 on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

I have set up an Ubuntu cloud server, and I need to use an older version of node.js for my environment.

Is that possible?

How do I install node.js 0.5 on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy?

Answer (score 2):

Did you even try and search for this?

Google: install old node.js

Result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js

> One way is to use NVM, the Node Version Manager. You can find it at https://github.com/creationix/nvm
>
> It allows you to easily install and manage multiple versions of node. Here's a snippet from the help:

```
Usage:
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version>
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
nvm ls                      List versions (installed versions are blue)
```